# What does "people who heard voices were definitely in the bottom ten" convey in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, reading

> ‘All dark,’ Dudley said hoarsely, shuddering. ‘Everything dark. And then I h-heard ... things. Inside m-my head...’
>
> Uncle Vernon and Aunt Petunia exchanged looks of utter horror. If
>   their least favourite thing in the world was magic, closely followed
>   by neighbours who cheated more than they did on the hosepipe ban,
>   **people who heard voices were definitely in the bottom ten**. They
>   obviously thought Dudley was losing his mind.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*</sub>

As I understand, "*people who heard voices were definitely in the bottom ten*" is saying that Uncle Vernon and Aunt Petunia disliked people who heard voices(because it's in the bottom ten of their favourite list). But I'm not sure how it's relevant to the context. Maybe, they thought Dudley was losing his mind because he heard voices? What's the sense of it here?

Comment: It seems you're asking why people who hear voices are in the bottom ten of their least favorite things list.  That's not a question about English.  The collocation "hearing voices" in the non-magic world is often a symptom of schizophrenia. Hence "they obviously thought Dudley was *losing his mind*", that is, "going crazy" (colloquial) or having a psychotic episode.

Comment: See also "seeing things", that is, hallucinating. They're not fond of "crazy people" or "crazies" (colloquial), formally, "the mentally ill".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, Why does "hearing voices" is a symptom of schizophrenia? I think this is the main point confuses me? Another thing is what "hear voices are in the bottom ten of their least favorite things list" means? is it "hear voices" is their favorite thing?

Comment: Hearing voices is a symptom of mental illness.  *Why* the mentally ill hear voices is a question better suited to a site about mental illness, not about English.  It is *people who hear voices* who are among their least favorite "things", along with magic and neighbors who disobey water conservation laws.  I suppose the phrase **bottom ten** could be confusing if the list is of least favorite things. Is the least favorite thing at the top of the list or at the bottom of the list?  You'll have to ask Rowling about that.

Comment: Perhaps it is a list of things that one can have a liking for or a disliking for, like a number line which includes negative numbers or a thermometer which goes below zero degrees. Their favorite things would be at the top, their least favorite at the bottom.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, I'm just curious a normal people can hearing voices and seeing things too. Maybe, they treat them as a kind of special terms in English? If I had known those are special terms for metal illness, then I wouldn't have been confused though.

Comment: But he heard things  "inside [his] head" and they thought he was "losing his mind".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, Oh!!! That explains! Thanks! It didn't put it in the following sentence: "people who heard voices were definitely in the bottom ten".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase *people who heard voices were definitely in the bottom ten* is explaining why Vernon and Petunia were so horrified at Dudley's statement. It is telling us that they had very strong feelings against people who hear voices in their heads. Then it clarifies that people hearing voices in their heads is not *quite* the worst thing in their opinion. They despise even more neighbors who cheat more than them, and the thing they most despise is magic.

Since we have now listed two things that are worse than people hearing voices in their heads, a further clarification is given to tell us that though there might be a few things worse than this, there are not that many things worse than this. People hearing voices in their heads is definitely one of the ten worst things in the Dursleys' opinion. That means that it is not the worst thing, and it is not the second-to-worst thing, but it is somewhere in the range of the third-to-worst thing to the tenth-to-worst thing, and we don't know enough about them to give a more precise determination.